# Disabling heatmaps from Autodesk Forge Datavisualization API

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to disable / hide the heatmaps of a model on certain events, reactivating them on other events, but I can't find any information on the documentation nor the API Reference. Is there any implementation of this yet or do I have to reload the geometry? What's the best approach on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable/hide the heatmap, we can just call `removeSurfaceShading()`. Before removing heatmap, we may need to remember the current heatmap setting somewhere in the app.

```js
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization').removeSurfaceShading()
```

While wanting to put it back, re-execute the codes you used to generate the heatmap. Here are the codes how the reference app achieves this:

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/a805e66597ff9ca27840ebee2fcba1985729ec61/client/components/HeatmapOptions.jsx#L163
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/a805e66597ff9ca27840ebee2fcba1985729ec61/client/components/BaseApp.jsx#L887

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to do this. I don't know if I'ts the intended way of hiding the heatmaps or no, but it worked for me.

To dynamicly disable the heatmap on the Forge Dataviz API, I've created an eventListener over a button like this :

```
 document.getElementById('maintenance-tab').addEventListener('click', async() => await viewer.unloadExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization'));
```

This will fully unload the extension. I've also tried the `updateSurfaceShading(()=> null)` function, but it didn't worked, the heatmap just sets to the lowest value. If you completely unload the extension the heatmaps AND sprites won't show.

In order to show them again, I had to call the function that loads the extension, adds the device data and renders the surface shading.

```
async function loadHeatmaps(viewer, model) {
    await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization');
    const dataVizExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization');
    const devices = [
     //ARRAY OF DEVICES
    ];
    const sensorColors = [0x00b2ca, 0x6fbf4a, 0xf7b53b, 0xe34f26];
    const sensorType = 'temperature';

const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model); // Obtain room info from the model
const shadingData = await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices); // Map devices to rooms
await dataVizExt.setupSurfaceShading(model, shadingData); // Build heatmaps for rooms with at least one device in them
dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors(sensorType, sensorColors);
normalizedValue = await getSensorValue();
const floorName = 'A1_Level 1';
dataVizExt.renderSurfaceShading(floorName, sensorType, (surfaceShadingPoint, sensorType) => normalizedValue);

}
document.getElementById('data-tab').addEventListener('click', async() => { await loadHeatmaps(viewer, viewer.model, ) });
```

This can be mapped to any event that does not depend on the dataviz api. This is the way I did it, and I repeat, I'm not sure this is the way intended by the developers. Any other answer is welcome.